# How to find the center of the browser window using JQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I find out the coordinates of the center of the browser using jquery?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why use jQuery? This can be done with simple enough plain JavaScript:

```
var horizontalCenter = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/2);
var verticalCener = Math.floor(window.innerHeight/2);
```

To use these, you may also have to append the units, `px` to the variables.

---

**Edited** to use [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) to force an integer value to the returned co-ordinates

Comment: It probably is a somewhat pointless use of jquery but I would still go for the jquery version because now when I see warning light go on in my head that says "this might not be cross browser compatible code".

Comment: @rtpHarry: well, there's definitely a use-case then; and I don't normally criticise use of jQuery, it's just that, occasionally, it can add more overhead than it saves is all. :)

Comment: I know what you mean, I have not really got involved too much in the whole javascript side of things but recently been playing with jQuery a lot. In fact I only really solidified that opinion when I was trying to think which I would choose to upvote and why. So thanks :)

Comment: @rtpHarry: a pleasure, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this makes sense:

```
var intWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
var intHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

var xCenter = intWidth / 2;
var yCenter = intHeight / 2;

alert("The center of the window is: " + xCenter + "x " + yCenter + "y");
```

Comment: This is not correct. Please check this page - http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/ . There's a comment there - `.innerWidth()` is not applicable to `window` and `document` objects.